# Accepting point geomerty parameters from function formal parameters in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgis

here is the code:

```
create function add_point(x integer, y integer) returns void as $$
begin
  insert into auto values(
    'point("'x|| ' '|| y'")',
    'point(0474735 1559415)',
    'point(0474757 1559414)',
    'point(0474751 1559496)',
    'SRID=20137;POLYGON((0474713 1559420, 0474735 1559415, 0474757 1559414, 0474743 1559471, 0474751 1559496, 0474748 1559498, 0474713 1559420))'
  );
end; $$ language plpgsql;

select add_point(0474713, 1559420);
```

during execution of `add_point` function it raises the following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "x" LINE 7: insert into auto values(
>   'point("'x|| ' '|| y'")','point(047...
>                                             ^
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "x" SQL state: 42601 Character: 126

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your `auto` table has 5 subsequent `geometry` columns. That is fine, but is it true? If not, you should use parentheses to separate the geometries that go on separate rows.

Your immediate error is related to the splicing of the parameters into the first `POINT geometry`:

```
insert into auto values(
  'point(' || x || ' ' || y || ')',
  ...
```

Comment: thank  you so much Sami and Patrick   it works with no error.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the way you make the points. It is also inefficient and error prone in other ways. There is no need to use string catenation when you could just use the parameters as numbers:

```
INSERT INTO auto VALUES (ST_point(x, y), ...
```

I would also change the other point definitions to use this format. This will ensure there will never be any problems with formats, catenations or anything.

Also setting the SRID for the points also might be useful, for that you can use `ST_SetSRID(ST_point(x, y), 12345)`